# Is there a way to list all GCC optimizations enabled at an optimization level (say -O2)?

Tags: gcc, compiler-optimization

I am currently using GCC 4.7.4 for building a small test app.

I am trying to play with some optimization options. So my question is the following:

Is there a way to list all GCC optimizations enabled at a given optimization level (say -O2) ?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#Optimization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I actually figured it out. This command did the trick for me.

```
gcc -Q -O2 --help=optimizers
```